# Expected binary browser location - traceback in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, unix, bots, geckodriver

I've just started building my first bot and I'm struggling with the first step: automating a browser.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/ker/Downloads/geckodriver")
browser.get("https://app.finxter.com/")
```

When I try running the code I get the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

I've installed the geckodriver unix executable and specified the path, but for some reason it still won't work and I can't really understand the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get this error message for two reasons:

1. Firefox isn't installed in your system.
2. Firefox isn't installed in the default location within your system.

Solution:

1. If Firefox isn't installed, install it on your system.
2. If firefox isn't installed at the default location, you need to pass the path of the firefox executable through an `Option()` instance:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r"C:/location/firefox.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="/Users/ker/Downloads/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://app.finxter.com/')
```

Comment: So, I installed Firefox and it works now, though it does give me this error message even though it works totally fine:
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/kerim/Downloads/geckodriver")

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your driver is executable
you can change the permission with the command below.

chmod +x /Users/ker/Downloads/geckodriver